# jquery ui autocomplete textbox for movies from remote datasource

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a call with the OMDb API which returns JSON data on movies when you make a call. While searching the movie am using an autocomplete functionality. I am getting the Movie name. But i want to show the result as shown in the attached file. (*Attached image with the file in highlighted color, 'Yellow'*).

I have tried with two different types, but am not able to get the expected result as mentioned in the attached file.(At the bottom of the file).

Please find the Codes
***First Code***
Here, am using cache too.

```
<div>
    <label for="tags">Movies: </label>
    <input id="myText" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cache = {};
        var getData = function (request, response) {    
            if (request.term in cache) {
                response($.map(cache, function (name, val) {
                    return {
                        label: name,
                        value: val
                    }
                }))
                return;
            }
            $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + request.term,
                function (callback) {
                    cache[request.term] = callback.Title;
                    response($.map(callback, function (name, val) {
                        if (val == "Title") {
                            cache[request.term] = name;
                            return {
                                label: name,
                                value: val
                            }
                        }
                    }))
                });
        };    
        var selectItem = function (event, ui) {
            $("#myText").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
        $("#myText").autocomplete({
            source: getData,
            select: selectItem,
            minLength: 3
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please see the Screenshot in the attached file.
Please see another Screenshot when few names have been typed and movies selected. Here, am getting one issue. am not getting the exact data typed in the search box. As you see, i have typed 'Titanic', but cache shows all the Movies names that have already searched or matching the search criteria.

**Second code screenshot is also attached**.

Please let me know how to show the results in the autocomplete search box with the movie title and with movie images.Also, how to load at least 5-8 movies when page loads using OMDb API.The search will return my results in the grid/table format.[Image with all the screen shot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIMsa.png)